# How to get my domain to point at my Windows 2012 R2 Server

Tags: dns, html, windows-server, domain-name

So right now I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 set up with Apache running and I'm in the point where I can only access my webpage by typing the ip address (123.456.789.000) into my browser.
I also have bought a domain name. (ex.com)

How can I make my domain "point" to my web server, so I can see my webpage by typing the domain name (ex.com) into my browser?

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the DNS of your domain such that it contains an A record which points either the apex record (represented by a * or @ usually) to your IP address or by adding an entry for www or something else that you want to prefix your domain.

Exactly how you do this will depend on which provider is hosting your DNS.

Some further guidance here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/dns/